# TeX accents do not seem to work with fontspec and xe/lua/latex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, luatex, accents

I am using Minion Pro as mainfont and it does not have in its glyph table the character `U+1E47 Latin small letter with dot below` which I need only **once** in my document. Rather than change to another font, I thought that I would generate it using `\d{n}`.

I give below a minimal file illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{Minion Pro} % Comment out optionally
\begin{document}
U+1E47 Latin small letter with dot below: \d{n}

U+0101 Latin small letter a with macron: \={a}
\end{document}
```

I do not get the desired letter `n with dot below` although the `a with macron` exists in the font and is available. Commenting out `\usepackage{fontspec}` gives the desired output with CMR as default font.

The behaviour is the same with xelatex and lualatex although the former indicates the missing letter with a crossed box.

I believe that with the `Ligatures=TeX` setting, I should be able to get missing letters using TeX accents. I do not think I need to load the `xunicode` package as it is already loaded by fontspec.

Can someone tell me what a I am doing wrong, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The "standard way" would be to say

```
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E47}{\d}{n}
```

in order to use the combining character instead of the missing character at U+1E47, but unfortunately Minion Pro has nothing in slot U+0323 (COMBINING DOT BELOW). We need to go the hard way: write the following in the preamble

```
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E47}{\d}{n}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother
```

so that you'll use the standard definition for `\d`. If other characters of that sort are needed, look in `xunicode.sty` for their definition; it starts with `\DeclareUTFcomposite`, it's sufficient to copy the line in your preamble and to change `\Declare...` into `\Undeclare...`.

Let's look also at the "line below", which is again missing in Minion Pro. Here's a similar way to cope with the case, using the macron (U+00AF) for emulating the line below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,newunicodechar}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % Comment out optionally

\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E47}{\d}{n}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E49}{\b}{n}
\makeatletter
\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\let\b\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\b}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-3ex}%
     \vbox to.2ex{\hbox{\char"AF}\vss}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}
\newunicodechar{ṉ}{\b{n}}

\begin{document}
U+1E47 Latin small letter n with dot below: \d{n}ṇ

U+1E49 Latin small letter n with line below: \b{n}ṉ

U+0101 Latin small letter a with macron: \={a}ā

\end{document}
```

It's perhaps better to declare `\b` and `\d` as robust commands. Moreover, with `newunicodechar` we can also input the characters directly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for solving and also explaining so that I can cope with future cases as well.

Comment: I am having a similar problem like @chandra. I am trying to get the letter "k" with a dot below with fontspec. It does not work, regardless of the font I choose. In LaTeX, I was able to do this with many fonts. Is there another simpler workaround to this? The solution proposed by @egreg is unfortunately beyond my level in LaTeX.This is my preamble: `\usepackage{fontspec} \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} \usepackage{xunicode} \usepackage{xlxtra}`

Comment: @mustail With the code above, `\d{k}` should give a dot below the "k".

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot, the code worked flawlessly for me. I was not able to get `\d{k}` work with Latin Modern and many other fonts before, when using `\fontenc`. Now I get the dot below the letter.

Comment: @egreg: A supplementary question if I may, please: The above workaround does not seem to work within a \textit{} argument i.e., for the italic version of Minion Pro, when I thought it should. Any help here is most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @chandra It works for me

Comment: @egreg: I am sorry for the noise. I mistyped it originally. It works for me too now! My apologies.

Comment: @greg: Supplementary question: I tried replacing `.` in the code above with `\_` to simulate \b{r} but the line below seems a bit long. What character should I use instead of `\_` to get a smaller line as in [4ed p 27] of the Kopka and Daly book *Guide to LaTeX*?

Comment: @chandra I've added also `\b{n}`

Comment: @egreg: Thank you very much: it works exactly! Thank you also for introducing me to the `newunicodechar` package. From my little knowledge, I think you have used the macron and moved its position from the top to the bottom to achieve the desired effect. Again, many thanks :-)

Comment: @egreg: Where do you get the definitions for `\d` and `\b` above? I need to re-define ā, ī, and ś because these characters do not work right with small caps on the font I am using. I need to adapt your definitions re-define `\=` and `\'` without modifying the lower-case definitions for these characters already in the font. Thanks.

Comment: @chandra It's better to start a fresh question with some details about the new problem.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I have found out that un-defining *already defined* characters for whatever reason is not that wise. If I re-define ā but not ū when both are already defined in the font, the macron placement seems different for the two. So, I need to investigate further before posting a fresh question.

Comment: @egreg First solution is working in document's body text, but not in `bibliography.bib` file, where I've tried to plug it in with this `{\d{s}}`?

Comment: @omtamal Please, ask a new question with the details.