# Dot below letter

Tags: xetex, accents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [TeX accents do not seem to work with fontspec and xe/lua/latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex)

Very frequently I need to write letters with dots below (like ḥ or ṭ) for transliteration. It's ok when the font I'm using comes with the character, but I can't use that character with other fonts.

It used to work with xelatex and xunicode package, I'd just use \d{t}, for example, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore, it just works if the font has that particular character.

Is there a way to "force" a dot below a letter in *any* font?

Here is the basic preamble I've been using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}

\Huge \d{o}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
voss@shania:~> pdffonts test3.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
POXWQN+MinionPro-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      5  0
```

Comment: I get `Missing character: There is no ọ in font Minion Pro Display/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `stackrel` package to place things above or below text. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
    $\stackrel[\textrm{.}]{}{\textrm{k}}$
\end{document}
```

I have used a period here, but you could probably substitute another character to serve as the dot, such as "˙".

Another option might be to change the font when placing the dot underneath. Look in the character map under "Combining diacritical marks". These are characters which essentially stacked in the same place as any character placed before. You may be able to use one font for the letter, then use another font for the diacritical mark.

Comment: even using \cdot, that places an awful lot of space between the k and its dot...

Comment: To make the dot closer, make it into an exponent. Use `$\stackrel[^\textrm{.}]{}{\textrm{k}}$`.

Comment: That's still pretty far off. Also, it messes up the vertical spacing. Compare your solution to `\d{k}` in running text.