# Special characters stopped appearing in text

Tags: unicode, characters, input-encodings

I have a unicode text (XeLaTeX) in which I use vowels with umlaut, like ü and ö, which worked but suddenly stoped working. These give an error message:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
>   (inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

Removed inputenc and babel and changed `\setromanfont` to `\setmainfont` from the `.sty` file and the ü and ö appear again.

But the command `\d{h}` to create ḥ no longer works as it did previously, the text simply produces h. The font does not have the desired glyph of its own. I am using XeLaTeX; most of the information below (and more) is in a `.sty` file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.3in,paperheight=9.45in]{geometry} 
\setromanfont[BoldFont={SeriaPro-Bold},ItalicFont={SeriaPro-Italic},BoldItalicFont={SeriaPro-BoldItalic}]{SeriaPro}
\begin{document}
```

The suggestion below to redefine \d works :

```
\renewcommand*\d[1]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][c]{\raisebox{-.45ex-\depthof{#1}}{.}}\llap{#1}}
```

Even better is a solution I found elsewhere:

```
\usepackage{xunicode}
```

Note: when used together with the `xlxtra` package it resulted in errors, so don't
Note: you cannot use this last solution at the same time as `\renewcommand*\d`

Comment: You don't have to load `inputenc` if you qre using xelatex; xelatex already expects input in unicode encoding.

Comment: Also, don't use `babel` with xelatex; use `polyglossia` instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You may also want to (i) rename `\setromanfont` to `\setmainfont` (the `\setromanfont` command is deprecated), (ii) replace the `=>` after `BoldItalicFont` with a simple `=`, and (iii) check whether your `paperwidth` and `paperheight` specifications are consistent with the documentclass option `a4paper`. Finally, the documentclass options `openright` and `twoside` are enabled by default for the `book` class and are thus redundant.

Answer (score 2):

[FF Seria Pro](https://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_seria_pro/) <sup>[Is this the correct font?]</sup> seems to not have the glyph `ḥ`:

Neither the [online preview](https://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_seria_pro/?&fg=000000&bg=ffffff&sample_size=12&sample_text=%20%E1%B8%A5&ft=liga) shows it, nor does it appear on one of the three pages of the [“complete character set”](https://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/fontfont/ff_seria_pro_regular/&s=c?acs_p=3).

Possible solutions:

1. You take `ḥ` from another font that is as close to Seria Pro as possible. (Bad)
2. You mimick it (build it yourself).
   With the help of the [`calc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/calc) you could do:

   ```
   \makebox[\widthof{h}][c]{\raisebox{-.45ex}{.}}\llap{h}
   ```

   Or, of course, make it your own macro:

   ```
   \newcommand*\doth{\makebox[\widthof{h}][c]{\raisebox{-.45ex}{.}}\llap{h}}
   ```

   Or, if you want to use the original char `ḥ` (it's XeLaTeX after all), make it active:

   ```
   \catcode`\ḥ=\active
   \newcommand*{ḥ}{\makebox[\widthof{h}][c]{\raisebox{-.45ex}{.}}\llap{h}}
   ```

   You may adjust the dimension `-.45ex` so that it looks good.
3. You use another font.
   This may be the best choice if you need to typeset a lot of those “funny” characters that don't exist in the chosen font!

---

If you need a lot of “under-dotted” characters you might even want to redefine the existing  `\d` macro to

```
\renewcommand*\d[1]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][c]{\raisebox{-.45ex-\depthof{#1}}{.}}\llap{#1}}
```

Comment: That last command indeed works out of the box! Very helpful.

Comment: @Willem You might find [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20791/4427) useful for your problem.