# How to generate compounded diacritical fonts for Sanskrit with XeTeX and LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to use diacritical marks for Sanskrit with a font that does not natively support all the marks (Minion Pro). So they are compounded somehow by XeTeX. This works almost fine in using:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec,newunicodechar}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\newunicodechar{Ṛ}{\d{R}}
\newunicodechar{ṛ}{\d{r}}
\newunicodechar{Ṝ}{\={\d{R}}}
\newunicodechar{ṝ}{\={\d{r}}}
\newunicodechar{Ḷ}{\d{L}}
\newunicodechar{ḷ}{\d{l}}
\newunicodechar{Ḹ}{\={\d{L}}}
\newunicodechar{ḹ}{\={\d{l}}}
\newunicodechar{ṃ}{\d{m}}
\newunicodechar{ḥ}{\d{h}}
\newunicodechar{Ṭ}{\d{T}}
\newunicodechar{ṭ}{\d{t}}
\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{\d{D}}
\newunicodechar{ḍ}{\d{d}}
\newunicodechar{Ṅ}{\.{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṅ}{\.{n}}
\newunicodechar{Ṇ}{\d{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}
\newunicodechar{Ṣ}{\d{S}}
\newunicodechar{ṣ}{\d{s}}

\begin{document}
a  A

ā  Ā

i  I

ī  Ī

u  U

ū  Ū

ṛ  Ṛ

ṝ  Ṝ

ḷ  Ḷ

ḹ  Ḹ

e  E

ai  Ai

o  O

au  Au

ṃ ḥ

k  K

c  C

ṭ  Ṭ

t  T

p  P

kh  Kh

ch  Ch

ṭh  Ṭh

th  Th

ph  Ph

g  G

j  J

ḍ  Ḍ

d  D

b  B

gh  Gh

jh  Jh

ḍh  Ḍh

dh  Dh

bh  Bh

ṅ  Ṅ

ñ  Ñ

ṇ  Ṇ

n  N

m  M

y  Y

r  R

l  L

v  V

ś  Ś

ṣ  Ṣ

s  S

h  H

\end{document}
```

But the macrons above Ḹ, ḹ, Ṝ, and ṝ are misplaced and thiner than the ones above ā, ī and so on. What can I do about that?

Second problem: This fails completely in LuaTeX. xltxtra seems to be essential for this to work. But this is not supported in LuaTeX. I tried this using this code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20791/19458

But the dots below are bigger than the i-dot. This is not the case with the solution above using XeTeX. Any idea how to do this in a better way in LuaTeX? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You're missing the `\UndeclareUTFComposite` declarations and the redefinition of `\d`. Probably also a redefinition of `\.` is necessary.

Comment: In XeTeX this works without `\UndeclareUTFComposite`. In LuaTeX even with `\UndeclareUTFComposite` the dots are too big with the solution cited above. How am I supposed to redefine `\d` and `\.`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is something that seems to work:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,newunicodechar}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E0C}{\d}{D}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E0D}{\d}{d}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E25}{\d}{h}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E36}{\d}{L}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E37}{\d}{l}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E43}{\d}{m}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E46}{\d}{N}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E47}{\d}{n}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E5A}{\d}{R}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E5B}{\d}{r}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E62}{\d}{S}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E63}{\d}{s}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E6C}{\d}{T}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E6D}{\d}{t}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E44}{\.}{N}
\UndeclareUTFcomposite[\UTFencname]{x1E45}{\.}{n}

\makeatletter
\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\let\.\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\.}[1]{\accent"02D9#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRON}[1]{\accent"AF#1}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{\d{D}}
\newunicodechar{ḍ}{\d{d}}
\newunicodechar{ḥ}{\d{h}}
\newunicodechar{Ḷ}{\d{L}}
\newunicodechar{ḷ}{\d{l}}
\newunicodechar{ṃ}{\d{m}}
\newunicodechar{Ṇ}{\d{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}
\newunicodechar{Ṛ}{\d{R}}
\newunicodechar{ṛ}{\d{r}}
\newunicodechar{Ṣ}{\d{S}}
\newunicodechar{ṣ}{\d{s}}
\newunicodechar{Ṭ}{\d{T}}
\newunicodechar{ṭ}{\d{t}}

\newunicodechar{Ṅ}{\.{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṅ}{\.{n}}

\newunicodechar{Ḹ}{\d{\MACRON{L}}}
\newunicodechar{ḹ}{\d{\MACRON{l}}}
\newunicodechar{Ṝ}{\d{\MACRON{R}}}
\newunicodechar{ṝ}{\d{\MACRON{r}}}

\begin{document}
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{
a  A
ā  Ā
i  I
ī  Ī
u  U
ū  Ū
ṛ  Ṛ
ṝ  Ṝ
ḷ  Ḷ
ḹ  Ḹ
e  E
ai  Ai
o  O
au  Au
ṃ ḥ
k  K
c  C
ṭ  Ṭ
t  T
p  P
kh  Kh
ch  Ch
ṭh  Ṭh
th  Th
ph  Ph
g  G
j  J
ḍ  Ḍ
d  D
b  B
gh  Gh
jh  Jh
ḍh  Ḍh
dh  Dh
bh  Bh
ṅ  Ṅ
ñ  Ñ
ṇ  Ṇ
n  N
m  M
y  Y
r  R
l  L
v  V
ś  Ś
ṣ  Ṣ
s  S
h  H
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see it's necessary to undo some of the work done by `xunicode` (which is automatically loaded by `fontspec` and needn't to be loaded explicitly). Also some of the standard accents must be redefined, or they wouldn't use the main document font.

### Update 2017

The macros above work provided `fontspec` is loaded with the `euenc` option. On the other hand, the new default TU encoding doesn't declare composites with `\d` or `\.N` and `\.n`, so the code is simpler.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\makeatletter
\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\let\.\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\.}[1]{\accent"02D9#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRON}[1]{\accent"AF#1}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{\d{D}}
\newunicodechar{ḍ}{\d{d}}
\newunicodechar{ḥ}{\d{h}}
\newunicodechar{Ḷ}{\d{L}}
\newunicodechar{ḷ}{\d{l}}
\newunicodechar{ṃ}{\d{m}}
\newunicodechar{Ṇ}{\d{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṇ}{\d{n}}
\newunicodechar{Ṛ}{\d{R}}
\newunicodechar{ṛ}{\d{r}}
\newunicodechar{Ṣ}{\d{S}}
\newunicodechar{ṣ}{\d{s}}
\newunicodechar{Ṭ}{\d{T}}
\newunicodechar{ṭ}{\d{t}}

\newunicodechar{Ṅ}{\.{N}}
\newunicodechar{ṅ}{\.{n}}

\newunicodechar{Ḹ}{\d{\MACRON{L}}}
\newunicodechar{ḹ}{\d{\MACRON{l}}}
\newunicodechar{Ṝ}{\d{\MACRON{R}}}
\newunicodechar{ṝ}{\d{\MACRON{r}}}

\begin{document}
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{
a  A
ā  Ā
i  I
ī  Ī
u  U
ū  Ū
ṛ  Ṛ
ṝ  Ṝ
ḷ  Ḷ
ḹ  Ḹ
e  E
ai  Ai
o  O
au  Au
ṃ ḥ
k  K
c  C
ṭ  Ṭ
t  T
p  P
kh  Kh
ch  Ch
ṭh  Ṭh
th  Th
ph  Ph
g  G
j  J
ḍ  Ḍ
d  D
b  B
gh  Gh
jh  Jh
ḍh  Ḍh
dh  Dh
bh  Bh
ṅ  Ṅ
ñ  Ñ
ṇ  Ṇ
n  N
m  M
y  Y
r  R
l  L
v  V
ś  Ś
ṣ  Ṣ
s  S
h  H
Ḹ  ḹ
Ṝ  ṝ
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, that's a wonderful solution that works both in XeTeX and LuaTeX. One more thing: Is there a way to make this searchable and copyable in pdf? If I copy + paste this I only get the seperated compound parts, not the whole symbol, e.g. `¯r.` instead of ṝ

Comment: Oh, and the dots remain a little bit bigger than the i dot which is not the case with my example. You can see this if you zoom in very closely. Well, it's not so important. I just wonder why it is this way.

Comment: You may be able to make the PDF file searchable with the help of the `accsupp` package; the cleanest solution is using a font that has the necessary glyphs.

Comment: Yes, `accsupp` could work. I will try this. Thanks alot!

Comment: This works indeed. Just replace `\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{\d{D}}` with '\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{% \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1e0c}% \d{D}%
\EndAccSupp{}% }' etc. Look up the hex code for each symbol. With this the symbols are copyable and searchable.

Comment: I find that the solution file from @egreg does not seem to compile successfully. I get this error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \UndeclareUTFcomposite
                          [\UTFencname]{x1E0C}{\d}{D}`. Can someone throw light on this development? Thanks.

Comment: @chandra This was for a previous version of `fontspec`; now to get this working you need `\usepackage[euenc]{fontspec}`. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. Invoking `\usepackage[euenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @chandra Updated answer

Comment: I am trying to get R, r, L, l, all with macron below.

I tried

`\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRONBELOW}[1]{\accent"0331#1}`

with `\newunicodechar{Ḻ}{\MACRONBELOW{L}}` etc., 

but am getting "tofu" in my PDF.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @chandra `\accent` doesn't really deal with underaccents

Comment: @egreg: Is there any other way to get these: I need them for accurate Romanization of Tamil letters according to ISO 15919. I would appreciate knowing. Thanks.

Comment: @chandra Please, make a fresh question with all the details.

Comment: @egreg: New question posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393486/generating-underaccents-for-romanized-tamil

Comment: One hint for anyone who, just like me, is looking to have diacritics for Sanskrit with this particular font (Minion): There is also another option. For some time, Adobe has released a revised version of this font, called "Minion 3". This version has the diacritics already built-in.