# Generating underaccents for Romanized Tamil

Tags: xetex, accents, indic, newunicodechar

ISO 15919 requires two Tamil letters, ற and ழ, to have lines below the letters like ṟ and ḻ in Romanized transliteration.

I want to use Minion Pro for this document because it is used elsewhere but it does not contain these glyphs.

I have tried generating these in accordance with [this schema](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/how-to-generate-compounded-diacritical-fonts-for-sanskrit-with-xetex-and-luatex).

However, it does not work: a failed minimum working example is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % Does not have the glyphs Ḻ  ḻ Ṟ  ṟ

% See egreg's example at:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/how-to-generate-compounded-diacritical-fonts-for-sanskrit-with-xetex-and-luatex

\makeatletter
\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\let\.\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\.}[1]{\accent"02D9#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRON}[1]{\accent"AF#1}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRONBELOW}[1]{\accent"0331#1} % Added by Chandra
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ḻ}{\MACRONBELOW{L}}
\newunicodechar{ḻ}{\MACRONBELOW{l}}
\newunicodechar{Ṟ}{\MACRONBELOW{R}}
\newunicodechar{ṟ}{\MACRONBELOW{r}}

\begin{document}
%
Ḻ  ḻ Ṟ  ṟ

\underline{R} ā
%
\end{document}
```

The "tofu" results [image: "Tofu latter and comparison between underling and macron.] are shown in the attached image. `\underline{R}` does work but the line below is thin compared to the line above in a properly formed a-macron: see image for comparison.

The `accents.sty` package does provide the `\underaccent` command but it works in math mode and I need something for text outside of math.

I am looking for a way to generate these letters repeatably and conveniently. How could I go about this, please?

Comment: `\underline{r}` ? or just use  ṟ directly in xetex (as long as your font has the character)

Comment: Please, add also a minimal (failing) attempt

Comment: @David Carlisle: I am using Minion Pro elsewhere and do not want to change the font.

Comment: @egreg: failed MWE has been added. I have just blindly extended your example elsewhere on TeX SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minion Pro has a very short supply of accents and combining characters.

Here's a workaround for the macron below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro} % Does not have the glyphs Ḻ  ḻ Ṟ  ṟ

\DeclareRobustCommand{\MACRONBELOW}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{%
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      #1\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip}
      \raisebox{-1.25ex}[.3ex][0pt]{\char"AF}\cr  
    }%
  }%
}

\newunicodechar{Ḻ}{\MACRONBELOW{L}}
\newunicodechar{ḻ}{\MACRONBELOW{l}}
\newunicodechar{Ṟ}{\MACRONBELOW{R}}
\newunicodechar{ṟ}{\MACRONBELOW{r}}

\begin{document}

Ḻ  ḻ Ṟ  ṟ \fboxsep=0pt\fbox{Ḻ}

L l R r

L l R r

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is swell; thank you @egreg. Am I right in guessing that you have constructed the macron below by translating the regular macron downwards, presumably because the U+0331 does not exist in Minion Pro.  How might I find out if a combining character is missing from a font?

Comment: @chandra On my system I have a utility that can display a Unicode character together with the fonts having it

Comment: May I suggest, @egreg, that you create a LaTeX package for diacritics embodying what's here, here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/how-to-generate-compounded-diacritical-fonts-for-sanskrit-with-xetex-and-luatex) and here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex) with the definitions of the characters as well. It would be a boon to those who need those characters.

Comment: @egreg You are my hero (one of a great), no words to say....