# Problems with accsupp and microtype

Tags: microtype, accsupp

I was building on egreg's solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/how-to-generate-compounded-diacritical-fonts-for-sanskrit-with-xetex-and-luatex) to provide missing accented characters for my document. I also added `accsupp` to make sure that the text is searchable.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with `accsupp` and `microtype`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\makeatletter \let\d\relax \DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]   
{\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\let\.\relax
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{% 
    \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1e0c}%          
\d{D}%
    \EndAccSupp{}%  
} 

\begin{document}
Ḍ
\end{document}
```

Not that the MWE works flawlessy, if `microtype` is commented out. With `microtype` enabled, it breaks.

Comment: It breaks also without accsupp. microtype seems not to like a redefined  Ḍ when loading the character tables. You can try to delay the redefinition with \AtBeginDocument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have no problems without `accsupp`. A simple `\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{\d{D}}` does not seem to bother `microtype`. `\AtBeginDocument` does indeed fix the problem though.

Comment: I meant that depending on the definition it can also break without accsupp. The problem is that acc supp is not robust. You could also move the accsupp setting inside the definition \d, or define a robust variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `\protect` in front of `\BeginAccSup` and `\EndAccSup` reveals the issue, via the warning

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ḍ (= \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1e0c}\d {D}\EndAccSupp{})'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU'.
(microtype)                Make sure it's a single character
(microtype)                (or a number) in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg/105(protrusion)'.
```

The error without the `\protect` happens at begin document, where `microtype` delays some setting.

In order to avoid prematurely redefining `Ḍ`, use `\AtBeginDocument`, so the conflict with `microtype` doesn't happen. This may have some consequences on protrusion, but already doing tricks for coping with missing characters in the font is bound to have typographic consequences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\makeatletter
\let\d\relax
\DeclareRobustCommand{\d}[1]{%
  \hmode@bgroup
  \o@lign{%
    \relax#1\crcr
    \hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth
  }%
  \egroup
}
%\let\.\relax
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newunicodechar{Ḍ}{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=1e0c}%
    \d{D}%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Ḍ
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure about why doing `\let\.\relax`, so I commented it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The commenting out was a copy/paste problem.

Comment: Thanks. After successfully compiling it, I made an interesting discovery. While I can now search for and copy/paste the character Ḍ with macOS's Preview, I can't do this in TeXShop's preview window although they supposedly use the same PDF routines …

Comment: @Simifilm Funny.