# Mixing fonts and microtype settings

Tags: fonts, fontspec, microtype

I am defining fall backs for missing glyphs in a font and I am partly building on @egreg's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84523/how-to-generate-compounded-diacritical-fonts-for-sanskrit-with-xetex-and-luatex).

Here's a MWE (never mind that the actual replacement defined here makes little sense):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\pagella{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
Ligatures={TeX}]
\newunicodechar{Ḍ}{% 
    \pagella{Ḍ}%
    }

\DeclareCharacterInheritance
   { encoding = {EU1,EU2,TU},
     family = {LatinModernRoman} }
   { D = {Ḍ,\pagella{Ḍ}}}

\begin{document}
Ḍ
\end{document}
```

This works insofar as Pagella is used to print Ḍ, but I am unable to tell `microtype` that it should also apply the font settings Latin Modern for this character. Although I use `\DeclareCharacterInheritance`, I still get the following error message:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ḍ (= \pagella {Ḍ})'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg/105(protrusion)'.
```

(I tried different variations of `\DeclareCharacterInheritance`, but none of them worked).