# How to increase size of the diacritic/accent mark selectively without changing the alphabet size

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, fontsize, accents

I am using a typeface that has limited support for letters with diacritics. I am looking to use the features in latex (I'm using xetex on ubuntu) for providing the glyphs I am missing.

My font has precomposed glyphs for dot-over-letters (like `ȯ`) but not for dot-under-letters (like `ḍ`). I know I can produce a dot under a d using `\d{d}` However the size of the dot in the precomposed glyph is much bigger than the size of the dot manually placed under by latex. This creates a bad look in cases where both diacritics occur in the same word.

Is is possible that I can tell latex to increase the size of the dot by some metric without affecting the size of the alphabet? Ideally I want to be able to do something like `\bigger_dot_under{d}`      instead of        `\d{d}`

where `\bigger_dot_under{}` is somehow defined to be 2x or 3x of `\d{}`, or in absolute mm/em metrics, point sizes or HUGE/Large terminology

Comment: Can you look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20791/4427)? It gives a way for redefining the under dot; where the period is produced, you can choose a different font where the period is bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked the solution to make it clean.  In the process, I've reduced it to a single routine called `\underdot`.  There are two parameters to adjust: `\dotscale` which is the size of the underdot and `\offset` which is the distance below the bottom of the letter at which the top of the dot begins.  The routine accounts for descended letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\dotscale
\newlength\offset
\newsavebox\newdotbox
\newsavebox\letterbox

\dotscale=.3ex         % DOTSIZE<---CAN CHANGE THESE
\offset=.25ex          % BELOW-BASELINE GAP ABOVE DOT

\def\newdot{\scalerel*{.}{\rule[-\dotscale]{1ex}{\dotscale}}}

\newcommand*\underdot[1]{%
  \sbox{\letterbox}{#1}%
  \sbox{\newdotbox}{\raisebox{-\dp\letterbox}{\raisebox{-\offset}{\newdot}}}%
  \usebox{\letterbox}%
  \hspace{-.5\wd\letterbox}%
  \hspace{-.5\wd\newdotbox}%
  \usebox{\newdotbox}%
  \hspace{-.5\wd\newdotbox}%
  \hspace{.5\wd\letterbox}%
}

\begin{document}

d\d{d}
\dotscale=.15ex\underdot{d}%
\dotscale=.4ex\underdot{t}%
\dotscale=.5ex\underdot{a}
p\d{p}
\dotscale=.4ex\underdot{p}%
\dotscale=.5ex\underdot{q}%
\dotscale=.15ex\underdot{g}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]