# Dot bellow letter in bibliography.bib file?

Tags: fonts, biblatex, xetex, fontspec, accents

Using the first solution in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex), we get a dot bellow the letter with `\d{s}` command, but how does this work in `bibliography.bib` file?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Minion Pro} % No problem with Computer Modern typeface

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\d}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author{\d{s}}, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

S with dot bellow: \d{s}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result of code above:

[image: bibliography]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Biber is too clever for you trickeries here. Since `\d` is a common way in TeX to input diacritics, `\d{s}` is automatically converted to `ṣ` by Biber and written to the `.bbl`.

One easy way is to use a different name for the fake macro

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dspec}[1]
   {\hmode@bgroup
    \o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\ltx@sh@ft{-1ex}.\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother
```

and then use `\dspec{s}` instead of `\d{s}`.

---

Or you turn off Biber's conversion with `--output-safechars`

```
biber --output-safechars
```

Comment: Both solutions working : )