# Minion Pro and breve under accent

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, accents

I am having a problem with Minion Pro and breve under accent (via `semtrans package` or via  ḫ). How can I adapt [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20791/48787) by @egreg to this case?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{semtrans}

\begin{document}

Test \U{h}. Test ḫ.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a better version that also keeps into account the slant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`semtrans` is no good for this, because it uses `\u` and Minion Pro lacks the combining breve (it lacks so many things it is not really good for extensive work).

We can patch the `semtrans` definition to directly use the breve character (at least Minion Pro has *something* in it).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

% from semtrans
\newcommand*\U[1]{{\oalign{#1\crcr\hidewidth
   \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\char"02D8}\vss}\hidewidth}}}
\newunicodechar{ḫ}{\U{h}}


\begin{document}

Test \U{h}. Test ḫ.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that also keeps into account the slant for italics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

% from semtrans, with changes
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\U[1]{{%
  \oalign{%
    #1\crcr
    \hidewidth
    \vbox to .2ex{\hbox{\kern-\f@size\fontdimen1\font\char"02D8}\vss}%
    \hidewidth\crcr
  }%
}}
\makeatother
\newunicodechar{ḫ}{\U{h}}


\begin{document}

Test \U{h}. Test ḫ. Test \U{m}.

\itshape

Test \U{h}. Test ḫ. Test \U{m}.

\LARGE

Test \U{h}. Test ḫ. Test \U{m}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The tick stealer strikes again.  Just before I wanted to post mine. :-) +1

Comment: @egreg What typeface do *you* prefer which is both aesthetic and suitable for extensive work. (Except, perhaps, `libertine`.)

Comment: @blackened It's not just a question of preferences; it also depends on what features you require from your font.

Comment: Since anyone transliterating stray Semitic words in an English context is likely to set them in italics, how would one define, say, a `\UI` command which would put the breve in the right spot for italics?

Comment: @Thérèse Done, without `\UI`. `:-)`

Comment: Just a minor thing, m with breve below does not exist.  The only letter with a breve below in Unicode is h.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's just for showing how the breve character is positioned with another letter.

Answer (score 9):

It never ceases to amaze me how powerful LuaTeX's callback mechanism is.  Here I hook into `pre_linebreak_filter`.  When I encounter an h with breve in the node list, I replace it by an ordinary h and inject a negative kern and a lowered breve character after it.

On the TeX level this is now completely transparent, no catcode changes required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local function hbreve(head)
    for n in node.traverse(head) do
        if n.id == node.id("glyph") then
            if n.char == 0x1e2b then
                n.char = 0x68
                local f = n.font
                local slant = font.fonts[f].parameters.slant
                local size = font.fonts[f].size / 2^16

                local breve = node.new("glyph")
                breve.font = f
                breve.lang = tex.language
                breve.char = 0x02D8
                breve.width = n.width

                local hbox = node.hpack(breve)
                hbox.shift = n.height
                head = node.insert_after(head,n,hbox)

                local kern = node.new("kern")
                kern.kern = -(n.width+breve.width+slant*size)/2
                head = node.insert_after(head,n,kern)

                local kern = node.new("kern")
                kern.kern = (n.width-breve.width+slant*size)/2
                head = node.insert_after(head,hbox,kern)
            end
        end
    end
    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", hbreve, "hbreve")
```

```
\begin{document}

Test ḫ.

\itshape Test ḫ.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I hesitate to ask, but could this be made to line up correctly even in italics?

Comment: @Thérèse In principle it is possible.  I extended the example to show how to access the slant in the current font but I couldn't work out the math to align it yet.

Comment: @HenriMenke The slant parameter is “slant per point” with unit points. As you see from my addition, I multiply it by the current fontsize using `\f@size`.