# Diacritics rendered differently by pdflatex, luatex, and XeLaTeX

Tags: diacritical-mark

I'm using diacritics, and notice that pdflatex, lualatex, and xelatex place the diacritics differently. For example, in pdflatex, \d{C} results in a dot precisely under the C, as it should appear. However, the dot is displaced to the left in LuaLaTex, and to the right in XeLaTeX. That's obviously incorrect. This also happens with many other characters.

Also, \textsc{} works perfectly when using pdflatex, but with the other engines, some letters remain lowercase.

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem would be appreciated. I may be using the font/fontspec incorrectly. Here is the header I'm using.

`\documentclass[11pt]{memoir} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{ebgaramond}`

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a problem with the RB Garamond font. and you might want to pick a different one that has the characters you need.

Comment: However, you can also [use this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex).

Comment: Thanks. Changing the font seems to have helped!

Comment: note that you should never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} ` with luatex or xetex

Comment: If I use the “true” EBGaramond fonts, not the ones in TeX Live, the dot under accent is placed correctly.

Comment: I mean those downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the EB Garamond font not containing the characters you need.  Switching to another font (for example, `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}`) will help.

Alternatively, you can [use this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex) to place a dot below a letter.