# Render Russian accent properly in XeLatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, accents

I struggle to include a Russian accent in my Latex document. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

\begin{document}

Mitropol{\textquotesingle}ski\u{\i}

\end{document}
```

This produces
[image]

Interestingly, the following works fine with PDFLatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  
\begin{document}

Mitropol{\textquotesingle}ski\u{\i}

\end{document}
```

The font can be downloaded here: https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Adobe-Caslon-Pro-Regular

Comment: **Do not use T1 font encoding in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc#comment1628303_664

Comment: (I think that alone should fix your problem, although I can't test because I don't have the font installed on my machine)

Comment: Didn't fix the problem.

Comment: removing `\XeTeXinputencoding latin1 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and saving the file as UTF-8 should fix it, certainly xelatex can not work with those settings, hyphenation (at least) will always be wrong

Comment: No it doesn't. I edited my question according to your comments.

Comment: Since your second MWE does not seem to load Adobe Caslon Pro: Are you sure that the font contains the relevant glyph?

Comment: can you demonstrate the problem using a generally available font or is it a specific issue with that font?

Comment: If I remove the Caslon line, xelatex [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqEs1.png)

Comment: Try `Mitropol\textquotesingle skiĭ Mitropol\textquotesingle ski^^^^012d` instead? By the way it's completely redundant to have the extraneous `{...}` around `\textquotesingle` (unfortunately [one of the highly-upvoted answers only site do that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202637/250119), I point out in a comment and in my answer but it's probably not as noticeable)

Comment: Seems it's with the Adobe Caslon Pro font. Is there a way to manually add the character ĭ to that font?

Comment: see fontspec manual section V: Commands for accents and symbols

Comment: does  `ski^^^^012d` or `skii^^^^0306` work? I would guess the first does not, but the second with a combining breve might, can not test without the font

Comment: Doesn't work either. Guess one needs to hack it in as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/tex-accents-do-not-seem-to-work-with-fontspec-and-xe-lua-latex

Comment: As far as I know, Adobe Caslon Pro is a commercial font and I don't think it can be downloaded freely. Are you sure that what's provided by the site you mention is an unadulterated copy of the *real* font sold by Adobe?

Comment: I use the font from the link. So I don't mind if it's the true Adobe font.

Comment: abobe caslon neither has the glyph ĭ  nor the combining accent for the breve. You could try `\setmainfont{LibreCaslonText-Regular.otf}` instead, it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe Caslon Pro neither has the glyph ĭ nor the combining accent for the breve, you could try libre caslon instead. It is larger, so you perhaps need to scale it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}

\begin{document}

Mitropol{\textquotesingle}ski\u{\i}

\fontspec{Libre Caslon Text}[Scale=0.85]

Mitropol{\textquotesingle}ski\u{\i}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Ulrike